# My project in Visual Studio is Read Only. What did I do?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, readonly

I must have done something wrong. I have a C# project in Visual Studio 2008. All of a sudden I see a lock on my classes and when I hover the class names on the top tab I see the class name as : C:\Myprojects\Oder.cs[Read Only] !

Has something weird like that happened to you before?

Comment: Do you have any type of Source Control on those files? If so, then you need to check them out before you can edit them (otherwise they're marked as read-only).

Comment: ...or select at them in Windows Explorer, right-click and uncheck the read-only setting under 'Properties'.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A couple of possibilities spring to mind:

Have you added the project to source control?

Have you marked the project folder (and all it's sub folders) as read only?

Of course, someone else may have done either of these things if they have had access to your machine.

Comment: Embarrassing, but my issue was that I somehow by accident started the debugger.

Comment: I added a project to source control. The folder was automatically set to read only, so I had to edit that.

Comment: @JasoonS me too, happens when pressing F5! Just go to "Debug" -> Stop Debugging to undo

Answer (score 31):

In my case it was a ReSharper 9.0/9.1 related issue. After clearing the ReSharper cache, I was able to edit files in my solution again.

Clearing the ReSharper cache can be done here: `ReSharper -> Options -> Environment -> General` and click: **Clear Caches** and restart your visual studio.

[image: Clearing the ReSharper cache]

*(The image is contained within the first of the linked JetBrains articles).*

JetBrains instructions:

[Ultimate Guide to Speeding Up ReSharper (and Visual Studio) - Performance degradation after ReSharper upgrade](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Ultimate+Guide+to+Speeding+Up+ReSharper+%28and+Visual+Studio%29#UltimateGuidetoSpeedingUpReSharper%28andVisualStudio%29-PerformancedegradationafterReSharperupgrade)

[ReSharper Online Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp80/Reference__Options__Environment__General.html)

Comment: Thank you, this was it, but how to keep it from ever doing that again? It does it on a recurring basis, with seemingly no pattern, frustrating.

Answer (score 17):

One Possible stupid thing.

Your project is still running and you forgot that. Stop debugging (CTRL + F5)

How do I know. Guess..

Answer (score 5):

Restarting my computer worked for me.  My project became read only in between compiles - suddenly I couldn't save changes to files, Visual Studio started presenting me with 'save as' dialog boxes, and SVN couldn't commit or clean the project because "sqlite could not write to readonly database."  Checking the file properties on the files in Windows Explorer showed that none of them were marked read-only.  I was able to make a backup copy of the project, then I restarted and it was fine.

Answer (score 3):

Restart your Visual Studio and add the project again. Worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Close, then reopen the file.

Still a pain, but at least it's less costly than completely closing visual studio.

Comment: Why has this answer been downvoted? It simply worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

You can try: file -> Source Control -> Go online

Answer (score 1):

IDE-integrated source control?

Comment: Just as likely to be non-IDE-integrated source control.

Comment: Was going off the padlock symbols - thinking they might have been put there by an IDE plugin. Clearly not, however...

Answer (score 1):

Much in line with what Morten Mertner said, (if you by chance are using TFS Source Control like I am) I did a manual checkout of the file and it resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your source files are or have been under source control. Many source control systems will set files to read-only when they haven't been checked out for editing.

[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com) makes it really easy to change file attributes recursively, but most likely Windows can also do this :)

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem is that the files are locked while the application is running.

In this state, Visual Studio 2013 displays the lock icon in the file tab and when you try to edit the file, a dialog box with this message appears:

*Changes are not allowed for this module as it was not built for changes while debugging or the target .NET runtime version does not support it.*

In Visual Studio 2015 as well, the  lock icon appears in the file tab when the application is running. but the dialog box and message are not displayed.

Stopping the application causes the file to become unlocked.